# How to use TypeORM with ExpressJS (project generated from Express generator)?

Tags: javascript, express, typeorm

I have an ExpressJS project, generated using the Express generator... I would like to use TypeORM in that project, how can I achieve that?

I have already tried to modify the `/bin/www` as follow :

```
typeorm.createConnection().then((connection) => {

  /**
   * Create HTTP server.
   */

  server = http.createServer(app);

  /**
   * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
   */

  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

but it did not work, I get: "default connection was not found" error everytime T try to use TypeORM in an ExpressJS route.

Answer (score 0):

Check where you are executing getManager/getRepository from typeorm. They need to be invoked after a connection is established.